# Splitting tables in C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have got a database which I already implemented in my Web API. I am working at a summer job and I have to use C# that I have never used before. I am not the best programmer but I know how to use java.

I need to split 4 columns each. In my database, there are 4 tables:

- `Name` (for the name of a station)
- `Date` (for the date the company measured the data)
- `FeedbackType` (it is a type of feedback. I got 4 types: Very Negative, Negative, Positive and Very Positive)
- `Count` (it describes how many people voted for this specific Feedbacktype).

Every `Station` has a column for every `FeedbackType` and my problem is to summarise the feedbacks. Very Negative gives 0 points, Negative gives 1 point, Positive gives 2 points and Very Positive gives 3 points. I have to multiply "Count" with the points given.

Down below you see a little bit of my json file

```
{
        "Name": "ASFINAG - Parkplatz Radin Nord",
        "Date": "01.07.2019 00:00:00",
        "FeedbackType": "Very Negative",
        "Count": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "ASFINAG - Parkplatz Radin Nord",
        "Date": "01.07.2019 00:00:00",
        "FeedbackType": "Negative",
        "Count": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "ASFINAG - Parkplatz Radin Nord",
        "Date": "01.07.2019 00:00:00",
        "FeedbackType": "Positive",
        "Count": 9
    },
    {
        "Name": "ASFINAG - Parkplatz Radin Nord",
        "Date": "01.07.2019 00:00:00",
        "FeedbackType": "Very Positive",
        "Count": 7
    },
```

This code is just one station just to show you an example of what i have to do

I hope it is not too hard to understand and I really hope you can help me
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Much as to an extent your question is clear, its too broad for SO as a whole. Please read [ask], [tour], and [mcve] .. show what you have, what doesnt work.. as SO is not here to give tutorials or write code for people.  Often lack of showing what you have results in closing very quickly and downvotes.  If you show what you have and explain more on what you're stuck (and its 1 short simple question even if it has much detail) it will more likely get an answer

Comment: Do you have any code that you've written so far? From the question its hard to advise without knowing a bit more about the code, for example have you got the data loaded into the program already, is it in a datatable, a dto etc

Comment: The data is already loaded in the program. I just want to summarise the feedbacks per station. I know the question is a little bit confusing and I am really sorry for that

Comment: Group by Name / FeedbackType, have a dictinary to map FeedbackType value to int multiplicateur. simple select g.count * dictionary[g.property]., sum in the name grouping

Comment: Your question isn't confusing but you need to show the code you have already, its like asking us to fix your car but haven't told us what car you have making it difficult to help as much as we'd like to

Comment: You probably mean to say "In my **table**, I have four **columns** " - correct?? Please be **precise** when formulating your questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Feedbacktype  by its value and have a total per company:

We need a way to store Feedbacktype and its respective value. Here we can use a simple array as index will be the value but we could use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) if the value change in the future

```
var feedbackValue = new string[] { "Very Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Very Positive" };
```

Finding the multiplicator value for a given feed back will be:

```
Array.IndexOf(feedbackValue, x.FeedbackType)
```

Then we [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) on Company name.
And [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum) the count and feedbackValue.

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Total = g.Sum(x =>
             x.Count * Array.IndexOf(feedbackValue, x.FeedbackType)
            )
    });
```

Result:

```
 { Name = Foo, Total = 40 },
 { Name = Bar, Total = 22 }
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jtav0L)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196469/discussion-on-answer-by-xdttransform-splitting-tables-in-c-and-sql).